# How to access class definitions in other modules from within a custom Gradle plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I am trying to create a custom Gradle plugin that reflects over the classes in the project (and its modules) against which the plugin is being applied. The idea is to generate some code based on the class files, but I don't know how to get hold of the references/classloader/jars for the other modules from within the plugin.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest using annotation processing.

Comment: You can use asm lib (https://asm.ow2.io/) for analyze your files or javassist (http://www.javassist.org/). It can works with java byte code and with java code (has 2 api). Or you can use annotation processing, but annotation processing can't use from gradle plugin.